# Python crashes when saving Keras model

Tags: python, keras

I am building a model in Keras that contains roughly 4.2M parameters. When I try to save the model using **`ModelCheckpoint`** or using `model.save('best_model.hdf5')`, Python crashes.

The model runs without any issues when I comment out the code, to save the model, so there isn't any other issue that could potentially be causing python to crash.

My reasoning here is that a large number of parameters is causing python to crash.
I have looked but haven't been able to find any solution.

Are there any alternatives available to save my model and reuse it in `Keras`? Or is there a way to fix this issue?

```
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_mean_squared_error', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
```

```
model.save(filepath)
```

Python doesn't shout out any error. This is all that pops up - 
[PythonErrorPopup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqb4x.png)

Comment: Could you provide the python error ?

Comment: @BenjaminBreton Python doesn't give out any error. A window pops up saying that Python has stopped working. You can find the screenshot here - https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqb4x.png

Comment: can you check the windows event log? it probably states more information

Comment: Are you using a mac machine?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Have you tried saving only weights - Default is save_weights_only=False ?

Comment: @RanSasportas I'll check and get back to you.

Comment: @AprajitaVerma No, it's a Windows machine.

Comment: @Prabindh Thank You ! I tried ```save_weights_only=True``` but python still crashed.

Comment: I doubt it is to do with size of model then. You might want to run the tests - https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/tests/test_model_saving.py#L126, also do some basic file checks (Is file created ? Is space available on disk ? etc.)

Comment: @Prabindh I'll run the test and update the question. Also, is there any other way if not Keras to save the weights?

Comment: What is the RAM or GPU? 
I do see that 4.2M params may be huge to be saved in one shot. Try to reduce the number of nodes/filters, etc and reduce the parameters.

Comment: Usually 4 million parameter shouldn't be too bad, it should be below 20Mb.

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa I am currently trying it on 8GB of RAM. I'll test it out on 32GB RAM to find out if RAM is the issue and update here.

Comment: @RanSasportas I checked the windows event log for this crash. The faulting module seems to be ```ntdll.dll```

Comment: @Dishanth, did you try reducing the model size?

Comment: @DishantSheth Did you fix this problem? I have the same issue

Comment: @AnandCU The issue fixed itself when I moved to a more stable version of TensorFlow.